# Getting Exception while trying to creating branch using GIT

Tags: git

vamshi.krishna@KRISHNA /c/Project Repo/diameter (master)
$ git branch develop
fatal: Not a valid object name: 'master'.

Can you please explain me why i am getting this exception?

I have a repository created in my local called "Project Repo"

In that folder i have executed git init

And i created diameter folder and placed all my src folder into diameter folder

And Now i want to push that into a new brach called develop for that reason I am trying to branch named "Develop".Since I am in master branch I want to create develop branch which is not executing..

CAn you please let me know the correct steps to create the branch and push my coe to the develop branch

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout -b develop
git add .
git commit -m 'initial commit'
git push origin develop
```

And read some git tutorial. You should know what you're doing.

**UPDATE**

To recreate master branch from already populated develop branch:

```
git checkout master
git merge develop
git push origin master
```

Comment: I can't see why I get -1 for my answer. In tutorial for which I gave you link you can find all things that you asked...

Answer (score 1):

Note: the reason you have that error message is, because you **haven't done any commit yet**, there is no 'master' branch.
A branch need a starting point (HEAD of another branch for instance) in order to be created.

So first create a commit (even an empty one: `git commit --allow-empty`).
Then you can `git checkout -b branch`, `git add everything`, commit and push your new branch.

See more on that topic (creating branches while there isn't any commit yet) in "[Creating branches on an empty project in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678699/creating-branches-on-an-empty-project-in-git)".