# Git create a branch without merging from default

Tags: git

To begin with, I'm pretty new to Git.

I have a default branch called `master` in my repo, I've created a new branch called `bugs` and added a `known_bugs.txt` file to it. The problem is that not only does Git add `known_bugs.txt` to the `bugs` branch, but it also shows all of the other files from the `master` branch inside of the `bugs` branch. Is there a way to simply not merge files from the default branch into a new one when the new branch is created?

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Do trees have "branches" that just float in mid-air, or do they start from the trunk of the tree? This isn't a question about merging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what happened is when you create a branch in git it's created from your current context. if you have nothing commited to master when you create a branch, your newly created branch will also be empty. if you have 2 files commited to master when you branch it will take that commit (2 files) and move them into your newly created branch.

so, if you want to make an empty branch you have a few options...

- **simple**: create all your empty branches before commiting anything.
- **moderate**: as soon as you create + checkout your branch remove (git rm) everything then add your files. the first commit to the new branch will remove and add all your files.
- **expert**: use the orphan flag to create a branch with no parent commits then remove all the files as stated before.

`git checkout --orphan NEWBRANCH`

(where NEWBRANCH is you branch name)

`git rm -rf .`

(remove all the files)

Answer (score 3):

I am new to git too. I've googled for a while and found three possible solutions. Hope that can help. You probably should not use a branch in this way though.

First, you could create a new branch `bugs` and check out this branch and then remove all file from the `master` branch, after that create your own file `knownbugs.txt` and make a commit.

```
git branch bugs
git checkout bugs
rm *
echo XXXX > knownbugs.txt
git commit -a -m "New branch with file knownbugs.txt"
```

Second, you can create an empty initial commit and derive your branch from it.

```
git commit --allow-empty
```

will do the work.

For more detail: [Creating branches on an empty project in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678699/creating-branches-on-an-empty-project-in-git)

Third, you could manually manage refs and index inside git:

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/bugs
rm .git/index
echo XXX > knownbugs.txt; git add knownbugs; git commit -m
git checkout -f master
git checkout bugs
```

Please refer to [Creating a git branch without ancestry](http://madduck.net/blog/2007.07.11:creating-a-git-branch-without-ancestry/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You could rebase your bugs branch to start from the very start of master. That way, its files would not be present in the other branch.